# Microsoft Bot Framework dialogs aren't handling Facebook location being sent

Tags: node.js, botframework, facebook-messenger

I need to be able to ask for the location and handle that in a waterfall dialog flow (currently I only care about Facebook Messenger)

I am wanting to ask for the location in a builder prompt, although the closest type is attachment but that is expecting a video or image response from the user.

I'd like to see a response handled by the user because the only way I can see this working is if I set a flag that I've asked that question and  explicitly capture the response if it is a location response. Although, this isn't really the functionality I'm after.

Does anyone have a solution for this by chance?

Thanks,
Scott

Edit; I am looking for a solution that requires the use of Location quick replies.

Answer (score 1):

For asking location, I would recommend you to use the [Bing Location Control for Microsoft Bot Framework](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location).

> The Bing location control for Microsoft Bot Framework makes the process of collecting and validating the user's desired location in a conversation easy and reliable. The control is available for C# and Node.js and works consistently across all channels supported by Bot Framework.

Comment: I have seen this and looks good if you're asking for users to type in their own address. I don't really need specific addresses, just areas. So I'm wanting to ask for their postcode (Australia) or their location from a facebook quick reply.